# How to add multi products in the same line in quotation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-10, odoo

As in the image of sales order line, I created many fields to add more products how can I make all prices computed and displayed in the unit price field
[image: Sales Order Line Image]

Thanks

Comment: In every 'Option #' field, are you adding a product? If so, what is your logic to calculate the price unit for that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create fields for glass, fly, option1 and option2 prices like unit price field like

x_XxX_P = fields.Float('XxX P', required=True, default=0.0)

Then create api on change for every new product column like

@api.multi

```
@api.onchange('x_XxX')
def product_id_change(self):
    if not self.x_XxX:
        return {'domain': {'product_uom': []}}

    vals = {}
    domain = {'product_uom': [('category_id', '=', self.x_XxX.uom_id.category_id.id)]}
    if not self.product_uom or (self.x_XxX.uom_id.id != self.product_uom.id):
        vals['product_uom'] = self.x_XxX.uom_id
        vals['product_uom_qty'] = 1.0

    product = self.x_XxX.with_context(
        lang=self.order_id.partner_id.lang,
        partner=self.order_id.partner_id.id,
        quantity=vals.get('product_uom_qty') or self.product_uom_qty,
        date=self.order_id.date_order,
        pricelist=self.order_id.pricelist_id.id,
        uom=self.product_uom.id
    )

    result = {'domain': domain}

    title = False
    message = False
    warning = {}
    if product.sale_line_warn != 'no-message':
        title = _("Warning for %s") % product.name
        message = product.sale_line_warn_msg
        warning['title'] = title
        warning['message'] = message
        result = {'warning': warning}
        if product.sale_line_warn == 'block':
            self.x_XxX = False
            return result

    self._compute_tax_id()

    if self.order_id.pricelist_id and self.order_id.partner_id:
        vals['x_XxX_P'] = self.env['account.tax']._fix_tax_included_price_company(self._get_display_price(product), product.taxes_id, self.tax_id, self.company_id)
    self.update(vals)

    return result
```

then create a field to calculate all prices

@api.depends('x', 'x', 'x_', 'x_', 'x_')

def _get_price_unit(self):

for line in self:

line.price_unit = line.x_ + line.x_ + line.x_ + line.x_ + line.x_